# Ranking model simulate click through

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, enterprise-search, ranking

Is there any API where I can pass the information about user clicks on the search results from an external user interface?

Comment: Back in the `search.asmx` days there was a `RecordClick` method on the service that accepted a URL. I have not looked, but I don't think it's available in REST. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Yeah, I have coincidentally found a method called RecordClick in the CSOM library, looks promising. I know that when you click on the search result it has some impact on its relevancy. I want to achieve the same effect when using an external gui.